OpenAPI Generator model validation skipping
YAML
    post:
      operationId: courses_instructor_api_get_student_progress_url_create
      description: Post method for validating incoming data and generating progress
        URL
      parameters:
      - in: path
        name: course_id
        schema:
          type: string
          pattern: ^[^/+]+(/|\+)[^/+]+(/|\+)[^/?]+$
        required: true
      tags:
      - courses
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/StudentProgressUrl'
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/StudentProgressUrl'
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/StudentProgressUrl'
        required: true



Its generated
schema looks like
    StudentProgressUrl:
      type: object
      description: Serializer for course renders
      properties:
        unique_student_identifier:
          type: string
          writeOnly: true
        course_id:
          type: string
        progress_url:
          type: string
          readOnly: true
      required:
      - unique_student_identifier

I have generated the client using this command
docker run --rm -v /Users/Documents/devstack/todo/21_nov.yaml:/local/21_nov.yaml -v /Users/Documents/devstack/todo/customclientskipval12:/local/out openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i /local/21_nov.yaml -g python -o /local/out

class StudentProgressUrl(BaseModel):
    """
    Serializer for course renders
    """ # noqa: E501
    unique_student_identifier: StrictStr
    course_id: Optional[StrictStr] = None
    progress_url: Optional[StrictStr] = None
    __properties: ClassVar[List[str]] = ["unique_student_identifier", "course_id", "progress_url"]

    model_config = ConfigDict(
        populate_by_name=True,
        validate_assignment=True,
        protected_namespaces=(),
    )


My question is unique_student_identifier write only but generated client while returning the response call cls.model_validate and it gives error because api response is missing the unique_student_identifier.
